# pivotal cloud foundry - java scheduled jobs

Tags: spring, spring-boot, cloud-foundry

I am using Java timer utility for some my scheduled jobs that are running outside PAAS platform.Does PCF support scheduled jobs running on java? I am also using Zookeeper in my current setup to keep of status of timers running across multiple nodes to ensure that same timer in not running in multiple instances of my nodes. Is a similar setup required for PCF and if so should Zookeeper be used for the purpose and is zookeeper supported by PCF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the @Scheduled annotation in your spring boot app.

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html

Comment: Thank You! In my existing env , I run this scheduled job in multiple nodes and use zookeeper to monitor these nodes and ensure only one instance of the job is running. Is a similar setup required when running scheduled jobs on PCF env? When a scheduled job terminates pre-maturely does PCF have any mechanism to handle this scenario or is there any recommended approach that should be followed?

Comment: we had a similar need, we ended up with a Spring Boot + Quartz integration that worked nicely for us. Quartz supports cluster-aware jobs, and maintaining the state of the jobs - misfired triggers, job failures etc. 
Here's a sample  in case you plan to go down this route. 
https://github.com/davidkiss/spring-boot-quartz-demo